# Is this possible to reset a single qubit that is part of a larger register in pytket?

Tags: quantum-gate, pytket

I want to reset a single qubit that is part of a larger register. Is this possible in pytket?

Resetting the single qubit

```
qc.add_gate(OpType.Reset,q_register[0])
```

throws

```
TypeError: add_gate(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
```

Resetting the whole register

```
qc.add_gate(OpType.Reset,q_register)
```

results in

```
RuntimeError: 30 args provided, but Reset requires 1
```

Maybe I just have the syntax wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question, it turns out that add_gate takes a list of unit ids

[pytket add_gate](https://cqcl.github.io/tket/pytket/api/optype.html)

Hence try:

```
qc.add_gate(OpType.Reset,[q_register[0]])
```